# making a servlet in netbeans and index.jsp

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets

i am trying to make a servlet in netbeans. It has to be called from an html form and take some data from it.

i overwrite doget and dopost putting just some testing outs in them.

when i try to run the servlet it only shows a hello word jsp page i found out that this was the index.jsp page that the servlet had by default.

How can i make the servlet run and actually make some output? other than the index welcome page?

Which url mast i use in order to call the servlet from the form?

th doget and dopost methods look like this

```
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                  HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException
    ResourceBundle rb =
    ResourceBundle.getBundle("LocalStrings",request.getLocale());
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");

    String title = rb.getString("helloworld.title");

    out.println("<title>" + title + "this is my anser</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("</html>");



   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
          this.doPost(request, response);}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can i make the servlet run and actually make some output? other than the index welcome page?

You should dispatch the request into the desired JSP page. You can do this with [`RequestDispatcher`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html).

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

> Which url mast i use in order to call the servlet from the form?

The one which you've mapped in `web.xml`.

You should also be putting HTML in JSP page only, not in servlet. It's also not a good practice to let `doGet()` and `doPost()` do the same. The `doGet()` is merely there to **preprocess** the data before displaying in JSP. The `doPost()` is merely there to **postprocess** the data after a HTML form submit.

In the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) about `[servlets]` tag here you can find a hello world example and more links about starting with JSP/servlets.